# How to use same development and distribution certificate for two developeres

Tags: ios, fastlane, iosdeployment

I need to use the same development and distribution certificate which was used by the other developer?

How can I do manual sign in this and build and distribute my app using fastlane firebase

Comment: you need the key to use them, easiest way to get both the key and cert is using p12 format. Ask him to open the keychain then choose the certs then export to p12 file and send it to you.

Comment: Then I have opened the p12 cert, but it not able to import in my xcode.

Comment: You can verify whether or not the cert was imported to keychain from keychain application, and it should be imported. After that, open your project setting, and search by key `code signing`, you will see the code signing identity, change from `iOS developer`, `iOS distribution` or `Apple ...` to something that has name of your coworker: `iPhone developer: name of him`

Comment: iphone developer not listed here

Comment: or apple development

Comment: Selected apple devwelopment. Can u prvide steps to see the p12 inside xcode

Comment: There's no p12 file in Xcode, p12 file contains two thing: the cert and the key for the cert. After installed (double click), it should be listed in keychain, from project setting if you don't see the new imported cert, please try close then reopen Xcode.

Comment: Okay thanks. I can able to see the list in the code signing. But the signing and capabilities it not listed. Shall i make fastlane build by this profiles. Does it works as expected

Comment: yes, it should work as expected with fastlane